# Hibernate Mapping issue with Tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I want to get rid of xml table mappings from my hibernate.cfg and replace them with references to classes themselves.

Here is what is used to have in my hibernate.cfg and what i'm replacing it with..

```
<mapping class="com.eugene.repository.mappings.Users"/>
    <!--<mapping resource="/mappings/Users.hbm.xml"/>-->
```

I can do that and then run tests from my local box and everything works well,
but when i create war file and upload it to tomcat, it cant resolve mappings..

What am i missing?

Comment: just make sure, your classes are in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder

Comment: Yes, they are, in WEB-INF/classes/com/eugene/repo...
not sure if that helps but hibernate.cfg is located in classes folder

Comment: Sir, did you get it to work yourself? Were you able to get tomcat to work with hibernate where tables where mapped via mapping class instead of mapping resource? I am not giving up on that but i'm still not able to get it to work